# Why could a calendar attendee of resource type respond with responseStatus: needsAction?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

Using Google API while creating a calendar event I get `needsAction` responses at seemingly random moments. The event is being created in a calendar for a Google Apps Resource. Why could a calendar attendee of resource type respond with responseStatus: needsAction?

Comment: Some actions (like moving the meeting to a different time) cause resetting of responses to needs action.

Answer (score 0):

The `responseStatus: needsAction` means that the user did not accept or decline the events that you set. Meaning they did not do anything on the event that you set. You can verify it by getting a specific event using the [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) just pass a `calendarId` and `eventId` that you want to get.

Here is the example output.

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "etag": "\"29xxxxxxxxx70000\"",
 "id": "xxxxxb4arxxxsu2xxxd8gc",
 "status": "confirmed",
 "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=xxxxxxxxYmI0YXI2MXN1MjkwNxxxxxxa2NhcmVhbxxxxx9nbGUuY29t",
 "created": "2017-01-03T12:57:20.000Z",
 "updated": "2017-01-14T10:08:08.985Z",
 "summary": "3-xxxxxx015xx3",
 "description": "Sample description -",
 "creator": {
  "email": "x@g.com"
 },
 "organizer": {
  "email": "x@g.com"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2017-01-11T12:00:00+08:00"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2017-01-11T12:25:00+08:00"
 },
 "iCalUID": "xxxxxxxxxxx@google.com",
 "sequence": 0,
 "attendees": [
  {
   "email": "a@google.com",
   "responseStatus": "needsAction"
  },
  {
   "email": "b@google.com",
   "responseStatus": "needsAction"
  },      
  {
   "email": "x@g.com",
   "organizer": true,
   "responseStatus": "accepted"
  },
  {
   "email": "m@google.com",
   "responseStatus": "declined"
  },
  {
   "email": "k@google.com",
   "self": true,
   "responseStatus": "accepted"
  }
 ],
 "hangoutLink": "https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/google.com/x?hceid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "reminders": {
  "useDefault": true
 }
}
```

The output tells you that `a@google.com` and `b@google.com` did not do anything in your calendar event invite, while `k@google.com` accepted it and `m@google.com` declined the event.

Comment: I know what `responseStatus: needsAction` means, the key here is that a **resource** responds with this response, and a resource is sth like a projector, a conference room. One would expect it respond with either accept or decline (when it's being used), and it _usually_ behaves like this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem recently, and apparently the fix is to set the responseStatus to 'accepted' before submitting the event.

It might look something like this:

```
attendees: [
  {email: resourceEmail, responseStatus: 'accepted'}
]
```